# glReadPixels GL_RGBA format

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl

I have app with erasing function. For example I open colored image, it adds grayscale layer on top of it, and with mouse I can erase top (grayscale) layer parts. Later there is ability to save image to file. If pixels for saving are taken as GL_RGB it works OK:

[image]

And if pixels for saving are taken as GL_RGBA i have some issues (the white space is transparent):

[image]

Original version of image is drawn to `framebuffer1`, then app draws brush strokes to `framebuffer2` and then grayscale version of image is drawn to `framebuffer3`. Then all these framebuffers are drawn to `main_framebuffer` and `main_framebuffer` is drawn to screen. Erasing is done via `glBlendFunc` and `glBlendFuncseparate`. When doing `glReadPixels`, pixels are readed from `main_framebuffer`. Where can be my problem?

---

***brigadir***

now I draw to main framebuffer like that:

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, _width, _height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glFrustum(0, _width, 0, _height, 0.1, 100);
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-0.5);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, main_framebuffer);
glClearColor(0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, _width, _height);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, framebuffer1_texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0, _height);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(_width, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(_width, _height);
glEnd();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE, GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, framebuffer2_texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, _height);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(_width, _height);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(_width, 0.0f);
glEnd();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, framebuffer3_texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, _height);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(_width, _height);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(_width, 0.0f);
glEnd();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glColorMask (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(0.0, oglAukstis);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(oglPlotis, 0.0);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(oglPlotis, oglAukstis);
glEnd();

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
glPopMatrix();
```

And when I try to load same image as earlier in this question I get:
[image]

And when I save it I get:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should disable writing to alpha channel of main buffer.

```
// draw framebuffers 1-3 ...
glColorMask (true, true, true, false);
// render to main buffer ...
glColorMask (true, true, true, true);  // revert to default state
```

Comment: came here to say this, looks like you beat me to it.

Comment: Julius, set `(true, true, true, false)` in first `glColorMask` call

Comment: Updated question. It doesn't adds alpha to framebuffer3_texture then, and erasing effect is not achieved

Comment: Okay. I reviewed your drawing steps and may propose to do next: remove  that two `glColorMask` calls; add one more step after all: set `glColorMask (0, 0, 0, 1)` and render white quad to framebuffer - it will make alpha channel of framebuffer opaque. If this will help, I may propose optimized variant without `framebuffer3_texture`.